# custom checkbox false or true after click

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm developing a `Checkbox` component, because the native one doesn't work because of Expo, so I decided to create a custom one, but I'm new to react native and I'm not able to change the state of my component after the click, what I need is that after the click, the box is unchecked, and if I click again, the box is `checked` again, but this only happens when the `checked` `property` is `true`. How do I change from true to false after the click?

**Index.tsx**

```
export interface Properties {
  newColor?: Boolean;
  id?: String;
  checked?: Boolean;
  onChange?: () => void;
  label?: String;
}

const Checkbox: React.FC<Properties> = (props: Properties) => {
  const config: Config = {
    types: [
      {
        title: "",
        isDefault: true,
      },
      "",
    ],
    modifiers: ["inverse"],
    states: ["disable"],
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          {...props}
          onPress={() => handleClick()}
          style={styles.container}
        >
          <View
            style={styles.checkboxUnchecked}
          >
            {props.checked === true ? (
              <View
                style={styles.checkboxChecked}
              >
                <Icon
                  name={"check"}
                />
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View
                style={styles.checkboxUnchecked}
              >
              </View>
            )}
          </View>
          {
            <Text>
              {props.label}
            </Text>
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

To use the component I call it this

```
<Checkbox checked={false} label={"Label"} id={"i3"}/>
```

**but the result i have is:**

[image]

**but if I call the component this way I get another result**

```
<Checkbox checked={true} label={"Label"} id={"i3"}/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use react state

Your code should be like this.

```js
const Checkbox: React.FC<Properties> = (props: Properties) => {

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(props.checked /*default value*/);


    const handleClick = () => {
        const newValue = !value; //switch value
        setValue(newValue);
        if(props.onChange) props.onChange(newValue);
    }


    return(

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleClick()}>

            {value === true  && <View style={styles.checkboxChecked}></View>}
            {value === false && <View style={styles.checkboxUnchecked}></View>}
        
         </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

use it like this

```js
<Checkbox
    checked={true} //defaultvalue
    onChange={value => alert("new value is: " + value)} //handle new value
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a question, how do I use props.onChange ?

Comment: use it to pass and handle the value outside the checkbox.

Comment: when i use it i get an error.
props.onChange is not a function. (In 'props.onChange(newValue)', 'props.onChange' is undefined)

Comment: i update my answer and i check if onChange is defined or no before call it `if(props.onChange) props.onChange(newValue);` , also add example how to use.

Comment: thank you so much, you saved my friday the 13th lol, i hope one day i can make it up to you. 
later I'll update your answer with my code in case someone needs to be able to use it.